# React: saving state of child component triggered by parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, parent-child, react-forwardref

Is there a way to do this?

I want to save a ChildComponent's state into an array state from the GrandParentComponent whenever I click a button from the ParentComponent?

Here's an overview of my components:

```
const GrandParentComponent = () => {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div>
      <ParentComponent array={array} setArray={setArray} />
    </div>
  );
};


const ParentComponent = ({ array, setArray }) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  
  const handleClick = () => {
    ref.current.setArray();
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>save</button>
      {array.map((item) => (
        <ChildComponent array={array} setArray={setArray} ref={ref} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const ChildComponent = forwardRef(({ array, setArray }, ref) => {
  const [childState, setChildState] = useState("")
  
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      setArray: () => {
        setArray((array) => [{ ...childState }, ...array]);
      }
    };
  });

  return <div>ChildComponent</div>;
});
```

The problem I'm encountering is it only saves the value of the last ChildComponent. What I want is to save all of the values from the ChildComponents.

What am I doing it wrong here? Or is there a better or correct way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: First of all you're passing the same ref to multiple mapped components which won't work (each mapped component will require its own ref), secondly you're storing one state inside another (but nowhere updating the child state?) on top of which the child state is a string but you're spreading it into an object? lots of question here.

Comment: It looks like you should just be using a [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

Comment: My mistake. The child state is an object not a string.

Comment: @pilchard thanks for the reply. I haven't thought about using a context. I'll try that one out next. Aside from context, are there other ways to do this? maybe a minor tweak that I can do instead of useContext?

Comment: You could pass an intermediary handler down from parent, and call it with identifying parameters from each child, but anything you come up with will be far more complicated than using a single state in a context